# How to make a table more vertically compact?

Tags: tables, amsmath

I finally managed to use the cases construct within a table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l p{7cm} ll}
\hline
a &  b & c \\
\hline
lalalalala   & \[ f := 
         \begin{cases} 
                    1 \text{if something}\\
                    2 \text{if something else}
         \end{cases}\] & $\tau_1 = 0.1$  \\
\hline
lalalalala & \[f := 
         \begin{cases} 
                    1 \text{if something}\\
                    2 \text{if something else}
         \end{cases}\]  & $\tau_2 = 0.1$  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

But the **braces** in column b take too much space vertically. That is there is too much white space above and under the braces. In other places in my document it is even more prominent.

This is the status quo:

[image]

and this is the desired outcome:

[image]

Please, how can I shrink a specific row of a table, without affecting the other rows?

Comment: Do you want to change the vertical space between some rows? If yes, you can use `\\[2ex]` for example when changing the line.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is only in the second column, not the entire row.

Comment: So, it is not clear to me what you want. Sorry.

Comment: @Sigur My bad. I edited the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\[...\]` introduces vertical space, as it effectively something like `\begin{center} ...\end{center}`, in math mode, however. so this has to be removed and changed to `\centering \( ....\)`

I kept the second line as demo for both effects.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l p{7cm} ll}
\hline
a &  b & b \tabularnewline
\hline
lalalalala   & \centering\( f := 
         \begin{cases} 
                    1 & \text{if something}\\
                    2 & \text{if something else}
         \end{cases}\) & $\tau_1 = 0.1$  \tabularnewline
\hline
lalalalala & \[f := 
         \begin{cases} 
                    1 & \text{if something}\\
                    2 & \text{if something else}
         \end{cases}\]  & $\tau_2 = 0.1$  \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ow, you won by few seconds.... lol I was suggesting  `\hfil $ ... $` instead of `\[ \]`.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: don't you think you should add the missing ampersands in the cases environments (and perhaps use `cases*`)?

Comment: @Bernard: I addressed the basic issue of the question, the vertical spacing first.

Comment: In my point of view, there should be nevertheless some spacing above the braces or otherwise the `\hline`s removed

Comment: I agree with you. But using, say, \addlinespace would look strange with respect to the question…

Comment: @Bernard `cases*`? What does `cases*` change compared to `cases`?

Comment: @Chritian Hupfer: You're automatically in text mode. Less typing.

Answer (score 5):

Just some improvements (in my opinion) to the preceding solution: I use the `cases*` environment (from `mathtools`), that makes the second column of a cases environment in text mode. The same package defines a `\coloneqq` command so that the colon is centred on the math axis. And finally I use the `booktabs` package to give some more vertical spacing to the rows, while I managed to have a smaller brace:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l p{7cm} ll}
\toprule
a & b & b \\
\midrule
lalalalala & \centering\( f ∶=
         \begin{cases*}
                    1 & if something \\[-0.25ex]
                    2 & if something else
         \end{cases*}\) & $τ_1 = 0.1$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]